# If I ignore you, the root Tag, I want to ignore your whole family

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

If I choose to ignore [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), shouldn't [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), [sql-server-2005](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005), [sql-server-20004](/questions/tagged/sql-server-20004) be ignored automatically for me? Otherwise, I'll have to fight them all for **years**.

Comment: SQL Server has a version 20004?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just add `sql-server*` to your ignored tag list. It will automatically ignore all variations stemming from [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

The reason the system doesn't do this automatically is because there is no semantic concept of a "root tag", and doing prefix-based ignores by default would create significant problems when it came to tags such as [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that. Thanks!