# Can we specify a pattern for favorite/ignored tags?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I ignore you, the root Tag, I want to ignore your whole family](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105413/if-i-ignore-you-the-root-tag-i-want-to-ignore-your-whole-family)

I know there are several similar questions on Meta, but I did not notice any of them proposed a simple pattern for adding favorite/ignored tags.

For an example, in SuperUser I want to ignore all Windows related questions, so the first thing I tried was to type "Windows*" in hope that will let me ignore all Windows tags. But nothings happened. Similarly, we can have "C++*" in StackOVerflow to add all C++ tags to the list of favorites.

People who made other questions proposed making some (deeply) nested hierarchy of tags. That complicates things a lot, and I agree with those who opposed that idea.

This simple pattern matching will do I think.

**Edit:**

My question was answered in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105413/if-i-ignore-you-the-root-tag-i-want-to-ignore-your-whole-family). (Thanks [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) for pointing this out.)

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105413/if-i-ignore-you-the-root-tag-i-want-to-ignore-your-whole-family), or something else?

Comment: Weird, i tried this... Thanks Tim!