# Ignore family of tags?

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

I know about [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105413/if-i-ignore-you-the-root-tag-i-want-to-ignore-your-whole-family), but the answer does not cover all possible options. For example, I don't know Java, so I would like to ignore questions regarding IDE for Java, all the numerous frameworks, including but no limited to Java-on-Linux etc. For the most part, they will not start with `Java-`, so I cannot block them like this `Java*`.

If you decide to introduce this feature, it could a community-managed tree-like structure, where you choose to either block the whole subtree, or drill-down and select some sub-items from it. For my example, it could be tags related to Java-on-Android that I would like to keep, even though the rest of Java is ignored.

Comment: Can you not block `*java*`?

Comment: @AlEverett: I could not find an example for Java tags, as I have so many to go through. But for PHP, an example is `symfony2 - an open source PHP web development framework`. It does not contain word PHP, so having * PHP * in ignored tags will not do any good.

Comment: Ah. What you want is quite far afield of what currently exists and would require a massive re-write. Further, a "tag tree" or "hierarchical tags" has been proposed, and rejected, multiple times.

Comment: Who downvoted? I did not find an identical topic and yes, I searched before posting. Ok, maybe I did not search for all possible word combinations - sorry about that. @AlEverett: Well, if many people need it, maybe you guys can still look into implementing this. Otherwise it's like "yeah, gasoline engines will require us a lot to rewrite, so we will stay on horses instead".

Comment: @Neolisk downvotes are different on meta, they indicate opinion, not the quality of the post (most of the time)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Ok, getting used to it. Is there anywhere I can vote on this feature?

Comment: "Can you not block *java*? "...For this specific example I could see problems with that approach (namely I don't care about java, but do care about javascript)

Comment: @kekekela Ignoring the [java] tat will not ignore the [javascript] tag.

Comment: ignoring asterisk-java-asterisk, as was suggested in the comment I was responding to, would

Comment: @kekekela has a valid point. If you ignore java*, it will ignore javascript, right? (which is not something you always want)

Comment: The vast amount of questions on java related things are also tagged java (or else the java people wouldn't see them)